# How to get the targeted element class name or id name in a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, classname

How can I get the targeted element class name or id name in a plugin?

for instance,

```
$('.class').pluginname();
$('#mymyid').pluginname();
```

I want to get `'.myclass'` and `'#myid'`

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What plugin are you using? Because it depends on the plugin, I think...

Comment: have a look here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523969/jquery-plugin-reload-the-plugin-itself) please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to use selector properties. For example:

```
$('.class').selector
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be possible unless you explicitly pass it as parameter to the plugin because if you have a list of DOM elements (which is what you have inside the plugin) you don't know which selector was used to fetch those elements, there might be different ways and selectors for getting the same set of DOM elements.